# Using multi-threading efficiently with million GET requests

Tags: python, performance, multithreading

**Disclaimer:** The following question is not related to any malicious activity. Only performance testing we are doing.

I am working on querying an internal server with lots of requests (~20 million).
I need it to be as fast as possible.

How the algorithm works:

- 30 Threads (because I found that more can slow it down) are running in the backgournd and checking a Queue.
- The `Queue` contains a list of strings that I am generating
- When a thread see that the Queue is not empty, it pull a string and using to send a `GET` request to the server.
- If some of the threads got a status code of `200` they will exit but my goal is to check the **WORST CASE** so in the example I am sending strings that will make a bad request (`404`)

Notice that if I send my server 20 million requests asynchronically it might crash. This is why the use of only 30 threads and a Queue doesn't crash my server.

Diagram:

[image]
The following is my code, I set `https://google.com` as the URL just for an example, `NUM_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 30` as the number of threads and `size = 100` is the size of requests I am sending - currently it just 100 for testing purpose.
My Code:

```
import time
import urllib3
import queue
import threading

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
https = urllib3.PoolManager()

# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466079/can-i-change-the-connection-pool-size-for-pythons-requests-module
def patch_https_connection_pool(**constructor_kwargs):
    """
    This allows to override the default parameters of the
    HTTPConnectionPool constructor.
    For example, to increase the poolsize to fix problems
    with "HttpSConnectionPool is full, discarding connection"
    call this function with maxsize=16 (or whatever size
    you want to give to the connection pool)
    """
    from urllib3 import connectionpool, poolmanager

    class MyHTTPSConnectionPool(connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool):
        def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
            kwargs.update(constructor_kwargs)
            super(MyHTTPSConnectionPool, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    poolmanager.pool_classes_by_scheme['https'] = MyHTTPSConnectionPool


patch_https_connection_pool(maxsize=160)


def try_get_request(some_string):
    # I put google.com as an example but it is an internal server
    url = 'https://google.com/' + some_string
    r = https.request('GET', url, headers={
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })

    return r.status

def queue_algo():
    NUM_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 30
    work = queue.Queue()
    global end_process
    end_process = False

    def worker():
        global end_process
        #print('****** TID %s: STARTED ******' % threading.get_ident())
        while not end_process:
            try:
                some_string = work.get(True, 3)
                #print("TID %s: Testing %s" % (threading.get_ident(), some_string))
                status = try_get_request(some_string)
                #print("TID %s: DONE %s" % (threading.get_ident(), some_string))
                if status == 200:
                    print('found 200 status code')
                    end_process = True
                    work.task_done()
                else:
                    continue
            except queue.Empty:
                continue

            work.task_done()

    threads = []
    for unused_index in range(NUM_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    queued = 0
    wait = False

    try:
        # The strings I am sending
        size = 100
        for i in range(0, size):
            work.put(str(i))
            queued += 1
            if queued >= size:
                wait = True
                break
        if wait:
            while work.qsize() > 0:
                time.sleep(5)
            end_process = True
            for thread in threads:
                if thread.is_alive():
                    thread.join()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        end_process = True
        for thread in threads:
            if thread.is_alive():
                thread.join()

start_time = time.time()
queue_algo()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I wrote it in Python and I have been told that this is not the best solution for using threads.
I also tried with `Go` also I don't have here an example of the code.
The current stats on my internal server are 100,000 requests with 30 threads in 2.6 minutes.
This is too much, I need to do it much faster.
Because I can't share with you my internal server I put `https://google.com` as an example for URL that can test it to check the times.

I wanted to know how you suggest to approach it ?  Maybe the architecture of using threads with Queue is not the best and there is a better one. Maybe Python is not the language for such stuff because of the GIL mechanism that threads are not working as a "real" threads.